# Linker errors with AvFormat with Cmake (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, cmake, libav

I'm trying to create a really simple program that will simply print the first frame of a video file to the screen using OpenGL. I have just started writing the program yet I have been stuck on a linker error when using Libav. I have googled the problem many times yet found nothing useful as I am using Cmake. However Cmake does compile, it just gets stuck when linking.
This file seems to be the real issue:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
}
bool load_frame(const char* filename, int* width, int* height, unsigned char** data) {
    AVFormatContext* av_format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!av_format_ctx) {
        printf("Couldn't created AVFormatContext\n");
        return false;
    }
    if (avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Couldn't open video file\n");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The two Cmake files work fine but here they are just in case:
This is the main one:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(autoedit C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDERD 14)

add_subdirectory(lib/glfw)
add_subdirectory(lib/FFmpeg)

add_definitions(-DGL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION)

if(APPLE)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-framework OpenGL"
        )
elseif(WIN32)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-lglu32 -lopengl32"
        )
else()
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-lGL -lGLU -lX11"
        )
endif()

list(APPEND SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    src/load_frame.cpp
)

add_executable(autoedit ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(autoedit FFmpeg glfw ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

And the secondary one:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(FFmpeg)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(AVCODEC     REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavcodec)
pkg_check_modules(AVFORMAT    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavformat)
pkg_check_modules(AVFILTER    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavfilter)
pkg_check_modules(AVDEVICE    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice)
pkg_check_modules(AVUTIL      REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavutil)
pkg_check_modules(SWRESAMPLE  REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswresample)
pkg_check_modules(SWSCALE     REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswscale)

add_library(FFmpeg INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
target_include_directories(FFmpeg INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVFILTER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_options(FFmpeg INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVFORMAT_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVFILTER_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVDEVICE_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVUTIL_LDFLAGS}
    ${SWRESAMPLE_LDFLAGS}
    ${SWSCALE_LDFLAGS}
)
```

It's very simple code yet when using the make command I am always getting:

```
usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/autoedit.dir/src/load_frame.cpp.o: in function `load_frame(char const*, int*, int*, unsigned char**)':
load_frame.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context'
/usr/bin/ld: load_frame.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `avformat_open_input'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/autoedit.dir/build.make:102: autoedit] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:136: CMakeFiles/autoedit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

As the error. I don't if it's something blatantly obvious and I'm being stupid. It should be a simple fix yet I don't quite understand what's going wrong. The functions seem to be present in the header file.If anyone has any idea of how to fix the undefined reference that would really help. Thanks in advance to anyone who can try and help.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but since you're using `IMPORTED_TARGET` with `pkg_check_modules`, you can replace the `target_include_directories` and `target_link_options` calls with a single `target_link_libraries(FFmpeg PkgConfig::AVCODEC ...)`

Comment: @Botje I don't know how, but that somehow fixed the issue. I'll let you know if it causes any other problems later though. Also what's the difference between what I did and what you recommended to me if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: If I were to guess, you also had to add `${AVFORMAT_LIBRARIES}` to the `target_link_libraries` call or somesuch. I like that the imported target does it for you :)